# Regresar un valor booleano e imprimir un mensaje en python

Tags: python, funciones, booleano

Estoy realizando una función que debe devolver `True` si los elementos de mi lista son números positivos y `False` si hay al menos un número negativo. Sin embargo, tengo un problema cuando quiero imprimir un mensaje si el valor booleano es `False`. ¿Cómo podría modificarlo, para que regrese el mensaje: *Tienes números negativos en tu lista*? Mi código es el siguiente:

```
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,-20,56,36]
def todos_positivos(lista):
    for i in lista:
        if i < 0:
            return False and print("Tienes números negativos en tu lista")
        else:
            pass
    return True and print("Todos los números son positivos")

resultado = todos_positivos(lista_numeros)
print(resultado)
```

Cuando en mi lista definida, pongo números positivos, sí me devuelve el mensaje tras resultar `True` pero no cuando hay un número negativo.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen día,

Imprime el texto antes de utilizar `return`.

Otra cosa que se puede mejorar de tu código es que no necesitas el `else` si cualquier número es negativo va a imprimir "Tienes números negativos en tu lista" y devolver `False` interrumpiendo el ciclo `for`. Si el ciclo termina sin ser interrumpido significa que todos los números son positivos.

Ejemplo:

```
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,20,56,36]
def todos_positivos(lista):
    for i in lista:
        if i < 0:
            print("Tienes números negativos en tu lista")
            return False
    print("Todos los números son positivos")
    return True

resultado = todos_positivos(lista_numeros)
print(resultado)
```

Ejemplo del funcionamiento:

```
# Valores de la lista 
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,20,56,36]

# Resultado
Todos los números son positivos
True

# Valores de la lista
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,-20,56,36]

# Resultado
Tienes números negativos en tu lista
False
```

**Edición:** Otra opción podría ser utilizar `any()` con un generador.

```
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,20,56,36]
def todos_positivos(lista):
    if any(i < 0 for i in lista):
        print("Tienes números negativos en tu lista")
        return False
    print("Todos los números son positivos")
    return True

resultado = todos_positivos(lista_numeros)
print(resultado)
```

**Edición 2:** Si únicamente tienes que devolver `True` o `False` podrías hacerlo más compacto

```
lista_numeros = [500,60,89,20,56,36]
def todos_positivos(lista):
    return False if any(i < 0 for i in lista) else True

resultado = todos_positivos(lista_numeros)
print(resultado)
```